# How to implement pathfinding and congestion detection with neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, path-finding, congestion-control

[image: Conveyor layout. A and B entry points and C and D exit points. There is a crossroad at position X]

This is a conveyor system. Boxes enter the system at A and move towards C where they exit the system. The same goes for B->D.

Boxes on path A->C have higher priority than boxes B->D. Boxes can stop and wait in each square. If there is a box on A2 and also on B2, the one from A2 should go through X first.

If there are boxes on C2, C1, A2 and B2 then the box from B2 should go through X and box on A2 shuold wait, until C1 is empty. Otherwise it would block the path B->D.

**How can I solve this problem with neural networks?**
So for every turn I would like to input the current state of each block and as a result I would like to get from where to where the next box should move.

For example:
System state: *BOX present at A1*
Result: *A1, A2*

I don't know if neural networks are a good tool for this problem, but I am just curious. 
Thanks for input :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a policy that maps state to action.

While you can use a neural network to store your policy you need some way to interact with the environment to collect data.

What you are describing is a typical Reinforcement Learning problem. I would suggest you have a look at Q-learning. For the size of the state space, you could easily store your policy in a table, but if you want, neural network are also easy to combine with Q-learning (though when using non-linear approximation schemes convergence is not ensured).